# Why my scala code works in IntelliJ IDEA but reports errors in cmd?

Tags: scala

New to scala.I want to verify that my configuration file is correct, so I write a helloword program.

```
    object HelloWorld{
      def main(args : Array[String]){
      println("HelloWorld")
      }
    }
```

WHen "scalac" the file in cmd it said `warning: 1 deprecation (since 2.13.0); re-run with -deprecation for details 1 warning`
but in the IDEA ,the code works.
What happens?

[code in IDEA and cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9ysg.png)

Comment: You dont have error but a warning. Your `.class` file might been generated also from the command line.

Comment: User, why would you remove relevant tags, and put images in links, and not inline? Please take the [tour], and read [ask].

Comment: It's a warning, not an error. In case you're curious, the warning itself is referring to how you've declared the function incorrectly - it should be `def main(args: Array[String]) = {...}` or `def main(args : Array[String]): Unit = {...}`. You're missing the equals sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would add to your `build.sbt` the following line:

```
ThisBuild / scalacOptions ++= Seq("-deprecation", "-Xfatal-warnings")
```

It will cause your compilation to fail when having such deprecation warnings. This is always a good practice to have. If you add this, you'll get the following compilation error:

```
[error] procedure syntax is deprecated: instead, add `: Unit =` to explicitly declare `main`'s return type
[error]   def main(args : Array[String]){
```

Then, when applying the suggestion, and adding a return type, such as:

```
object HelloWorld {
  def main(args : Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("HelloWorld")
  }
}
```

You get no warning and `HelloWorld` is printed as expected.